# Fetch data from localstorage and perform some string operation on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, offline

I am having several entries in localStorage. Now I am to fetch all data from localStorage and perform **replace** action on it.

E.g.

```
for(var i=0; i<window.localStorage.length; i++) {
var strKey = window.localStorage.key(i);
var sKey = strKey.replace("abc","")
console.log(sKey +"\n");
```

}

In such case I am not able to get the required result. "abc" is not getting replaced.

Answer (score 0):

to set the new value in the localstorage...you need to call the setter to set the value for the keys.

If you want to modify the key itself, then you have to delete the old key and update the localstorage object with the new key.

```
for(var i=0; i<window.localStorage.length; i++) {
var strKey = window.localStorage.key(i);
var sKey = strKey.replace("abc","")
localStorage.setItem(strKey, sKey);
console.log(sKey +"\n");
}
```